# How to prevent Horizontal RecyclerView to pass Scroll to parent ViewPager when list is scrolled to end?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have layout something like this:-

[image]|

My problem is whenever RecyclerView scrolls to one of the end point of list. It transfer touch event/scroll event to ViewPager, which then swipe the whole page. In My requirement I don't want ViewPager to swipe whole page, when user interacting with RecyclerView even if list is exhausted while scrolling.

Comment: Add this to your recyclerview `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

Comment: I  tried android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false", but this is not working. Moreover this is not supported for API 19 (which is the minimum support that I'm giving.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this @charlie

Comment: No. Our product team changed the design